# joining 2 table with queryover

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I have 3 table in a sample. i am going to join 2 table but i have problem 
the following is my code :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

```
</configSections>

<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
  <session-factory>
    <property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver</property>
    <property name="connection.connection_string">Server=(local);database=human;Integrated Security=SSPI;</property>
    <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2008Dialect</property>
    <property name="proxyfactory.factory_class">NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.ProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

```
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.Text; 
using System; 


namespace human {

public class TblStudent {
    public TblStudent() { }
    public virtual int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<TblTerm> TblTerms { get; set; }
    public virtual string name { get; set; }
    public virtual string lastname { get; set; }
}
}


using System; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.Text; 
using FluentNHibernate.Mapping;

namespace human {


public class TblStudentMap : ClassMap<TblStudent> {

    public TblStudentMap() {
        Table("TblStudent");
        LazyLoad();
        Id(x => x.ID).GeneratedBy.Identity().Column("ID");
        Map(x => x.name).Column("name");
        Map(x => x.lastname).Column("lastname");
        HasMany(x => x.TblTerms);
    }
}
}

using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.Text; 
using System; 


namespace human {

public class TblTerm {
    public TblTerm() { }
    public virtual int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual TblLesson TblLesson { get; set; }
    public virtual TblStudent TblStudent { get; set; }
}
}

using System; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.Text; 
using FluentNHibernate.Mapping;

namespace human {


public class TblTermMap : ClassMap<TblTerm> {

    public TblTermMap() {
        Table("TblTerm");
        LazyLoad();
        Id(x => x.ID).GeneratedBy.Identity().Column("ID");
        References(x => x.TblLesson).Column("LessonID");
        References(x => x.TblStudent).Column("StudentID");
    }
}
}

using System; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.Text; 
using FluentNHibernate.Mapping;

namespace human {


public class TblTermMap : ClassMap<TblTerm> {

    public TblTermMap() {
        Table("TblTerm");
        LazyLoad();
        Id(x => x.ID).GeneratedBy.Identity().Column("ID");
        References(x => x.TblLesson).Column("LessonID");
        References(x => x.TblStudent).Column("StudentID");
    }
}
}

 private void button_JoinSelect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var cfg = new Configuration();
        PersistenceModel pm = new PersistenceModel();
        pm.AddMappingsFromAssembly(typeof(human.TblStudent).Assembly);
        pm.Configure(cfg);
        ISessionFactory factory = cfg.BuildSessionFactory();

        using (var session = factory.OpenSession())
        {
            using (var trans = session.BeginTransaction())
            {
                var query = session.QueryOver<TblStudent().JoinQueryOver<TblTerm>
      (c=> c.TblTerms).List();
                trans.Commit();
                dataGridView1.DataSource = query;
            }
        }
      }
```

My Error :

NHibernate.Exceptions.GenericADOException: could not execute query
[ SELECT this_.ID as ID1_1_, this_.name as name1_1_, this_.lastname as lastname1_1_, tblterm1_.ID as ID2_0_, tblterm1_.LessonID as LessonID2_0_, tblterm1_.StudentID as StudentID2_0_ FROM TblStudent this_ inner join TblTerm tblterm1_ on this_.ID=tblterm1_.TblStudent_id ]
[SQL: SELECT this_.ID as ID1_1_, this_.name as name1_1_, this_.lastname as lastname1_1_, tblterm1_.ID as ID2_0_, tblterm1_.LessonID as LessonID2_0_, tblterm1_.StudentID as StudentID2_0_ FROM TblStudent this_ inner join TblTerm tblterm1_ on this_.ID=tblterm1_.TblStudent_id] ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name 'TblStudent_id'.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ConsumeMetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, DbAsyncResult result)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader()
   at NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher.ExecuteReader(IDbCommand cmd) in d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\AdoNet\AbstractBatcher.cs:line 247
   at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.GetResultSet(IDbCommand st, Boolean autoDiscoverTypes, Boolean callable, RowSelection selection, ISessionImplementor session) in d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Loader\Loader.cs:line 1349
   at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoQuery(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters, Boolean returnProxies) in d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Loader\Loader.cs:line 413
   at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters, Boolean returnProxies) in d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Loader\Loader.cs:line 243
   at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoList(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters) in d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Loader\Loader.cs:line 1694
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoList(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters) in d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Loader\Loader.cs:line 1703
   at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.ListIgnoreQueryCache(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters) in d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Loader\Loader.cs:line 1601
   at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.List(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters, ISet`1 querySpaces, IType[] resultTypes) in d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Loader\Loader.cs:line 1595
   at NHibernate.Loader.Criteria.CriteriaLoader.List(ISessionImplementor session) in d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Loader\Criteria\CriteriaLoader.cs:line 74
   at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.List(CriteriaImpl criteria, IList results) in d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Impl\SessionImpl.cs:line 1919
   at NHibernate.Impl.CriteriaImpl.List(IList results) in d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Impl\CriteriaImpl.cs:line 265
   at NHibernate.Impl.CriteriaImpl.List[T]() in d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Impl\CriteriaImpl.cs:line 276
   at NHibernate.Impl.CriteriaImpl.Subcriteria.List[T]() in d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Impl\CriteriaImpl.cs:line 813
   at NHibernate.Criterion.QueryOver`1.List() in d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Criterion\QueryOver.cs:line 57
   at NHibernate.Criterion.QueryOver`1.NHibernate.IQueryOver.List() in d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Criterion\QueryOver.cs:line 198
   at human.Form1.button_JoinSelect_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in E:\desktop\Human\human\human\Form1.cs:line 84

Please advise me

Comment: what is the full exception text?

Comment: could not execute query [ SELECT this_.ID as ID1_1_, this_.name as name1_1_, this_.lastname as lastname1_1_, tblterm1_.ID as ID2_0_, tblterm1_.LessonID as LessonID2_0_, tblterm1_.StudentID as StudentID2_0_ FROM TblStudent this_ inner join TblTerm tblterm1_ on this_.ID=tblterm1_.TblStudent_id ] [SQL: SELECT this_.ID as ID1_1_, this_.name as name1_1_, this_.lastname as lastname1_1_, tblterm1_.ID as ID2_0_, tblterm1_.LessonID as LessonID2_0_, tblterm1_.StudentID as StudentID2_0_ FROM TblStudent this_ inner join TblTerm tblterm1_ on this_.ID=tblterm1_.TblStudent_id]

Comment: with full brainboost meant `exception.ToString()` not `exception.Message`

Answer (score 0):

That exception could be a result of many reasons. For example, I've got the same error when just trying to run your code over my db without your tables at all. Try to check if any one record from any your table returned well then try to make your join work. I see no error, when i configured nh properly, no exceptions was thrown. Try this code instead of your factory initialization (on new fresh db), it creates tables from your mappings to see if your real tables are same.

```
ISessionFactory factory = Fluently.Configure()
            .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<TblStudent>())
            .ExposeConfiguration(config => new SchemaExport(config).Create(false, true));
```